# Sum using nested WorksheetFunction

Tags: vba, loops, sum, nested-function

I am trying to create a function that sum every iteration of a worksheetfunction used in my UDF (in my case : normal law). Here is what i've done :

```
 Function Normalaw(x, mean, sigma)

For i = 1 To 30

Normalaw = WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.Norm_Dist(x, mean * i, sigma, True))

Next

End Function
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `Normalaw = Normalaw + WorksheetFunction.Norm_Dist(x, mean * i, sigma, True)`

Comment: Thanks, it work like a charm!